# Merging of multiple databases into a Single database without any duplicate entries

Tags: database, sqlite

I have multiple databases that contain the table name as city and it has a name, population entries.

```
for /r %%i in (*.db) do sqlite3 -header -csv %%i .dump >> SAN.sql

sqlite3 final.db < SAN.sql

sqlite3 -header -csv c:/sqlite3/final.db "select DISTINCT * from  city ;" > tracks.csv
```

I have fetched the entire database from the current directory and dumped it into the SQL file(SAN.sql)
  By using the Sqlite tool I copied the entries from the SQL file (SAN.sql) into the database final.db.
  I have exported the data from the final.DB into the tracks.csv file to remove the duplicate entries by using DISTINCT.
 After removing the duplicate entries the tracks.csv looks like as follows:

```
            name,population
            Abilene,115930
            Akron,217074
            Albany,93994
            Albuquerque,448607
            Alexandria,128283
             Allentown,106632
             Amarillo,173627
             Anaheim,328014
```

I want to convert the tracks.csv file into a database(.db). Please guide me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Other than the  `c` in `c:/sqlite3/final.db` (which is not right) this has nothing to do with C.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a table from a CSV file with the `.mode` and `.import` commands:

```
$ sqlite3 a_new_db.sqlite                                                                                               SQLite version 3.28.0 2019-04-16 19:49:53
Enter ".help" for usage hints.

sqlite> .mode csv

sqlite> .import tracks.csv tracks

sqlite> select * from tracks;
Abilene,115930
Akron,217074
Albany,93994
Albuquerque,448607
Alexandria,128283
Allentown,106632
Amarillo,173627
Anaheim,328014
```

See [CSV Import](https://sqlite.org/cli.html#csv_import) for more details.